# /proc/meminfo MemTotal =?

Tags: linux, memory

**What elements of `/proc/meminfo` sum up to `MemTotal`?**

Example of `tee /tmp/proc/meminfo < /proc/meminfo`

```
MemTotal:        1279296 kB
MemFree:          164092 kB
Buffers:           62392 kB
Cached:           378116 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:           715176 kB
Inactive:         307800 kB
Active(anon):     583268 kB
Inactive(anon):     3384 kB
Active(file):     131908 kB
Inactive(file):   304416 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
Dirty:                44 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        582480 kB
Mapped:           112904 kB
Shmem:              4192 kB
Slab:              47524 kB
SReclaimable:      33588 kB
SUnreclaim:        13936 kB
KernelStack:        1568 kB
PageTables:        12092 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      639648 kB
Committed_AS:    1298132 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:       24012 kB
VmallocChunk:   34359696868 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:     77824 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:        8832 kB
DirectMap2M:     1300480 kB
```

Here are snippets that helps me in checking different configurations:

```
# Let's load them into CLI variables
all=$(sed 's!:[^0-9]\+!=!;s! kB!!;s![()]!_!g' /tmp/proc/meminfo) ; eval $all
# Let's make overview sorted by values (helps in tracking missing one)
echo $all | sed 's! !\n!g' | sort -n -k 2 -t '=' 
# Let's try Memtotal=MemFree+Active+Cached+Buffers ? (should be zero)
echo $[ $MemTotal - $MemFree - $Active - $Cached - $Buffers ]
# But gives -40480
```

What am I missing? Which elements of `/proc/meminfo` should I sum to get `MemTotal`?

Comment: You're assuming the format includes redundant information. I'm not sure, but I think it's possible that all the fields are actually useful... maybe MemTotal tells you something you can't calculate from all the other numbers. The `free` tool displays "total, used, free" memory, and it calculates `used = total - free` itself rather than looking for a "Used" field in meminfo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure everything you need is exposed in `/proc/meminfo`'s output so that you can calculate `MemTotal` yourself. From the [Linux Kernel's documentation `proc.txt` file](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

*excerpt*

```
MemTotal: Total usable ram (i.e. physical ram minus a few reserved
          bits and the kernel binary code)
```

#### dmesg

If you look through either the output of `dmesg` or the log file `/var/log/dmesg` you can find the following information:

```
$ grep -E "total|Memory:.*available" /var/log/dmesg
[    0.000000] total RAM covered: 8064M
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 2044843
[    0.000000] Memory: 7970012k/9371648k available (4557k kernel code, 1192276k absent, 209360k reserved, 7251k data, 948k init)
```

I believe this information can be used to determine `MemTotal`. This blog post covers it in more details, it's titled: [Understanding “vmalloc region overlap”](http://www.embedded-bits.co.uk/2011/vmalloc-region-overlap/). Also  this post, which provides some additional info, titled: [Anatomy of a Program in Memory](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/anatomy-of-a-program-in-memory).

#### References

- [How do I account for all of the memory in meminfo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406691/how-do-i-account-for-all-of-the-memory-in-meminfo)
- [How to Calculate MemTotal in /proc/meminfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508913/how-to-calculate-memtotal-in-proc-meminfo)