# Why is UID information not in /proc/X/stat?

Tags: linux, proc

This is a silly question for the sake of academics; I know where to get the `UID` information if I need it. According to the proc(5) man page:

```
       /proc/[number]/stat
              Status information about the process.  This is used by ps(1).  It is defined in /usr/src/linux/fs/proc/array.c.

       /proc/[number]/statm
              Provides information about memory status in pages.  The columns are:

       /proc/[number]/status
              Provides much of the information in /proc/[number]/stat and /proc/[number]/statm in a format that’s easier for humans to parse.
```

I find it interesting that `stat` doesn't contain information about the `UID`, `EUID`, etc. of a process, yet `status` does. Kind of odd that one is forced to use the "human readable" file instead. Does anyone happen to know the reason for this off-hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When handling data, much of the time, the key is to keep only data that's relevant to your particular set of tasks, and nothing more. Much of the data that's exposed under `/proc` is done so for a singular purpose, i.e. a tool that needs to have visibility to it etc.

Given the comments I would assume 3 things about `/proc/[number]/stat`:

1. The data being displayed here is what's relevant to functions and data objects within `/usr/src/linux/fs/proc/array.c`.
2. That data is also what's relevant to `ps`.
3. Looking through the data that's here you'll notice that there is nothing here that's user specific. It's all geared towards processes.

**NOTE:** for #2. this is the process data that's relevant to `ps`. The processes owned by a user are kept in a different data structure within the Kernel elsewhere.

On the otherhand, with `/proc/[number]/status`, the comment pretty much tells you what this data is geared towards, a human reading it. So it's likely that this node within the Kernel serves no other purpose, from a tools perspective, then to collate data from other sources into a single place for the user to consume it.

#### Additional evidence

If you need more proof of this, look to this question I answered a while ago, titled: [/proc/meminfo MemTotal =?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/proc-meminfo-memtotal/84766#84766). This question covered `/proc/meminfo` and it was a similar issue here too. Some of the data is exposed during the Kernel boot-up under `dmesg` log output. However that data, though memory related and perceived as relevant to `/proc/meminfo` was absent, again because it wasn't useful to:

1. the target audience of tools that would be using `/proc/meminfo`
2. Not relevant to the Kernel internal functions, methods, and data structures that made use of the data in `/proc/meminfo`.

#### References

- [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 - ps command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ps.html)

Comment: Assumptions #1+#3 are probably close to the mark. #2 I'm less sold on, as `ps` does in fact need to be able to display `RUID` and `EUID` for a process depending on the format. They're probably looked up with syscalls instead of via /proc at that point.

Comment: Yes I should've qualified that bullet a little bit more. I meant the data related to a process, that relevant to `ps`. I'll update the A.

Comment: @AndrewB For the record, `ps` looks it up in `/proc/<pid>/status`! It uses both the `stat` and `status` files, because neither contains all the bits of information it needs (uids are only in `status`, controlling terminal is only in `stat`... it's a mess).