# different kernels report different amounts of total memory on the same machine

Tags: kernel, configuration, meminfo

I have two x86_64 kernels compiled on the same machine against the same code (4.15.0 in [Linus' source tree](https://github.com/torvalds/linux)).

The config files were produced by running `make localmodconfig` against that source, using different, larger original config files coming from different distros: Arch and Slackware respectively. I'll nickname them

**arch** [config](https://pastebin.com/vXd4w34R)

and

**slk** [config](https://pastebin.com/NWrCCDab)

for that reason.

The issue: running `cat /proc/meminfo` consistently reports about 55-60 MB more in the MemTotal field for **arch** than for **slk**:

`MemTotal: 32600808 kB` for **arch**

vs

`MemTotal: 32544992 kB` for **slk**

I say 'consistently' because I've tried the experiment with the same config files against earlier versions of the source (a bunch of the 4.15-rc kernels, 4.14 before that, etc., rolling over from one source to the next with `make oldconfig`).

This is reflected in the figures reported by htop, with **slk** reporting ~60MB less usage on bootup than **arch**. This is consistent with the [htop dev's explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41224738/how-to-calculate-system-memory-usage-from-proc-meminfo-like-htop) of how htop's used memory figures are based on `MemTotal`.

My question is: any suggestions for which config options I should look at that would make the difference?

I of course don't mind the 60MB (the machine the kernels run on has 32 GB..), but it's an interesting puzzle to me and I'd like to use it as a learning opportunity.

Memory reporting on Linux is discussed heavily on these forums and outside in general, but searching for this specific type of issue (different kernels / same machine => different outcome in memory reporting) has not produced anything I found relevant.

---

**Edit**

As per the suggestions in the post linked by @ErikF, I had a look at the output of

`journalctl --boot=#`

where `#` stands for 0 or -1, for the current and previous boots respectively (corresponding to the two kernels). These lines do seem to reflect the difference, so it is now a little clearer to me where it stems from:

**arch** (the one reporting larger MemTotal):

Memory: 32587752K/33472072K available (10252K kernel code, 1157K rwdata, 2760K rodata, 1364K init, 988K bss, 884320K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)

**slk** (the one reporting smaller MemTotal):

Memory: 32533996K/33472072K available (14348K kernel code, 1674K rwdata, 3976K rodata, 1616K init, 784K bss, 938076K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)

That's a difference of ~55 MB, as expected!

I know the **slk** kernel is larger, as verified by comparing the sizes of the two vmlinuz files in my /boot/ folder, but the brunt of the difference seems to come from how much memory the two respective kernels reserve.

I'd like to better understand what in the config files affects *that* to the extent that it does, but this certainly sheds some light.

---

**Second edit**

Answering the questions in the comment by @Tim Kennedy.

> Do you have a dedicated GPU, or use shared video memory

No dedicated GPU; it's a laptop with on-board Intel graphics.

> and do both kernels load the same graphics driver?

Yes, i915.

> Also, compare the output of dmesg | grep BIOS-e820 | grep reserved

As you expected, does not change. In all cases it's 12 lines, identical in every respect (memory addresses and all).

---

**(Final?) edit**

I believe it may just be as simple as this: the kernel reporting less MemTotal has *much* more of the driver suite built in; I just hadn't realized it would make such a noticeable difference..

I compared:

`du -sh /lib/modules/<smaller-kernel>/modules.builtin`

returns 4K, while

`du -sh /lib/modules/<larger-kernel>/modules.builtin`

returns 16K.

So in the end, I believe I was barking up the wrong tree: it won't be a single config option (or a handful), but rather the accumulated effect of many more built-in drivers.

Comment: Possibly related answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/84695/proc-meminfo-memtotal

Comment: That helps, thanks! Edited the post to relay new information.

Comment: A couple of things to validate would be which kernel modules are built in, and which modules are loaded dynamically, and which are actually loaded.  Do you have a dedicated GPU, or use shared video memory, and do both kernels load the same graphics driver?  Also, compare the output of `dmesg | grep BIOS-e820 | grep reserved` (ought not to change on the same maching, but you never know).

Comment: Thank you! Added that as __Second edit__ above. Incidentally, the post might grow unwieldy, what with all of the edits; is it common practice to always just edit the original when new info becomes available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the picture is as in my last edit above; I just did not know enough about the process of reserving memory to realize when I asked the question: it all boiled down to the larger kernel having more of the drivers built in rather than modularized.

Incidentally, I did want to put this to some (remotely) practical use: I wanted to have as slim a kernel as I could, but still boot it without an initrd. I knew that

- the smaller kernel (moniker **arch** above) is very lightweight and fast to boot, but not without an initramfs;
- the larger kernel (**slk**) *will* boot without an initramfs, but takes longer.

So I made a compromise that I think I'll stick with for now. I took the two config files, call them **large** and **small**, and made sure that every unset config option in **small** is reflected in **large**.

First,

```
awk '/^# CO/ {print} small > staging'
```

grabs all lines in the **small** config file that are of the form

`# CONFIG_BLAH is not set`

and dumps them in a **staging** text file. Then,

```
for i in $(awk '{print $2}' staging) ; do sed -i "s/^$i=./# $i is not set/" large ; done
```

takes all lines from the config file **large** that set (via `=y` or `=m`) an option contained in **staging** and unsets them.

I then ran `make oldconfig` on the resulting file **large** in the kernel source directory and compiled. It all went through all right:

- the new kernel boots some 3 seconds faster
- without an initramfs
- is much smaller in the sense that its `/lib/modules/<kernel>/modules.builtin` got cut down in half, from 16K to 8K.

---

Those are not much to write home about, but as I said this was puzzling me.. I think I'm all set on the issue now.

Presumably the more straightforward thing to do would have been to figure out once and for all *precisely* which drivers I need on this machine in order to boot without an initramfs, but I'll leave that for some other day. Besides, playing off one config against the other was a fun exercise in its own right.